# Huawei P20 Pro charging in USB host mode

Tags: usb, charging, usb-on-the-go, usb-host-mode

I'm seeing several related questions here. However, most of them are ancient (as in 2012) and refer to micro USB and maybe the USB-C standards are different with regard to host mode charging.

I'm using my P20 Pro as a tactical flight computer with two connected devices.
The first one is a single row mini usb keyboard and the second a flight vario which sends position and elevation data to the software.

```
   P20Pro
     |    
mini USB-Hub
  /     \
KBD     Vario
```

What I'm missing in this setup is how to power the phone.

I would need something like this:

```
   P20Pro
     |\
     | \Portable Power Bank
     |      
mini USB-Hub
  /     \
KBD     Vario
```

This is just some background info. The question could also be *How to charge the P20 Pro while a usb keyboard and mouse is connected?*

Basically (at least according to Huawei's online chat support) the device supports charging in host mode since their [MateDock 2 adapter](https://consumer.huawei.com/at/accessories/huawei-matedock/) also charges the phone.

However, the MateDock 2 would be an overkill since I don't need a HDMI/VGA port.
In addition I'm not sure what the MateDock is exactly and if it also redirects *non standard* USB devices.

Another solution would be wireless charging but the P20 doesn't support this technology.

So what is the the 2018 answer to charging in USB OTG host mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this (and use an HDMI monitor) by using a USB C Power Delivery hub, and a PD charger. The hub included as well an HDMI output, but it's cheap (around 30€). 
I think I used this one [here](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B0786CZ6XY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00).
I bought two different ones but the second one does not seem to be available anymore on Amazon and the link does not work anymore.
The charger I used is an [USB C PD 41W charger from Auckly](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B077RQDB9Z/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s02).

Comment: The answer really seems to be the USB Power Delivery (PD) standard. However, I'd love to see a phone with 3 USB ports instead of 3 cameras ;)